# Django function based view allow is_active user whereas ClassBasedView does not allow is_active user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I have 2 views. One is function based and the other is class based. When I call the function based view with an **is_active** user, django does not throw any errors but when I call the class based view it returns **403 error**.Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes

@require_POST
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated,])
def test_function_based_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({
        'success': "True",
    })

class TestClassBasedView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({
            'success': "True",
        })
```

> Django Version 1.11.21

Comment: First question: is the indentation correct? Because the code you show here is absolutely not and this could be the reason.

Comment: the indentation is correct, besides if indentation was the issue then the django app wouldn't even run.

Comment: indentation has been updated.

Comment: Okay. Now that that's out of the way, I would recommend you to replace `@require_POST` with `@api_view(('POST',))` (`from rest_framework.decorators import api_view`)

Comment: does this effect permissions in any way?

Comment: it does - `api_view` is the decorator that handles the transformation of the function view into an `APIView` - where the `permission_classes` are actually checked. source code: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/decorators.py#L18

Comment: Exactly. I have had problems with this too previously and in the end the solution was the most obvious one, which was using DRF decorators with DRF class based views to avoid integration problems such as this one.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the problem is not that the class based view is returning a 403 error, but rather that the function based view is not checking the permissions correctly. This might be caused because `@require_POST` does not take the permissions into consideration.

Replace `@require_POST` in your function based view with `@api_view(('POST',))`.